# Embedded Scala REPL Interpreter example for 2.10

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Please give a code example of how to create an embedded Scala REPL interpreter programmatically, that works in Scala 2.10. *(I added this Q&A after spending hours combing various code scraps to get a working interpreter)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Example `Repl.scala`:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings


object Repl extends App {
  def repl = new ILoop {
    override def loop(): Unit = {
      intp.bind("e", "Double", 2.71828)
      super.loop()
    }
  }

  val settings = new Settings
  settings.Yreplsync.value = true


  //use when launching normally outside SBT
  settings.usejavacp.value = true      

  //an alternative to 'usejavacp' setting, when launching from within SBT
  //settings.embeddedDefaults[Repl.type]

  repl.process(settings)
}
```

Some notes

- I choose to show the JLineReader (default) rather than `SimpleReader` because it works much better, correctly handling arrow keys, delete etc. JLine does add an jar dependency.
- The example shows how to bind values into the repl (variable `e` above).
- When I omit `settings.Yreplsync.value = true`, the REPL hangs and is useless.
- From my testing, if both `usejavacp` and `embeddedDefaults` settings are combined together, an error results

I find this easiest to test via SBT; a sample `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Repl"

organization := "ExamplesRUs"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.2",
 "org.scala-lang" % "jline" % "2.10.2"
)
```

Sample SBT session:

```
> run-main Repl
[info] Running Repl
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
e: Double = 2.71828

scala> 2 * e
res1: Double = 5.43656

scala>
```

Comment: I answered this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/18418634/1296806 but I don't think I tried 2.10, and I always forget that -Yrepl-sync option. Also haven't been using sbt console. Thanks!

Comment: There was also this question about binding values and class loaders http://stackoverflow.com/a/18503457/1296806  I can't tell if it's good info because it was ignored. Where is crowd think when you need it?

Comment: @som-snytt Yes, your answer was the single most useful source for this example

Comment: doesnt work with scala 2.11 as "method loop cannot override final method"

Comment: @simbo1905 For 2.11, instead override createInterpreter and just call super().createInterpreter() before calling the intp.bind.

Comment: How can bind all local scope to the REPL? (In latest version)

Answer (score 4):

Based on Ben's excellent answer, below is a helper class to ease starting the interpreter.  Usage:

```
Repl.run(("e", "Double", 2.71828), ("pi", "Double", 3.1415))
```

It automatically detects when you're running from SBT and accommodates.

Repl.scala:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import java.io.CharArrayWriter
import java.io.PrintWriter

object Repl {

  def run(params: (String, String, Any)*) {

    def repl = new ILoop {
      override def loop(): Unit = {
        params.foreach(p => intp.bind(p._1, p._2, p._3))
        super.loop()
      }
    }

    val settings = new Settings
    settings.Yreplsync.value = true

    // Different settings needed when running from SBT or normally
    if (isRunFromSBT) {
      settings.embeddedDefaults[Repl.type]
    } else {
      settings.usejavacp.value = true
    }

    repl.process(settings)
  }

  def isRunFromSBT = {
    val c = new CharArrayWriter()
    new Exception().printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(c))
    c.toString().contains("at sbt.")
  }

}
```